# Android drop shadow radius

Tags: android, drop-shadow

I'm working on to get a drop shadow.

The closest one I can get is to do with gradient-radius.

The code is as below:

```
<item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:height="84dp"
                android:width="84dp"/>
            <corners android:bottomRightRadius="40dip"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="40dip"
                android:topRightRadius="40dip"
                android:topLeftRadius="40dip"/>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/black"
                android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
                android:type="radial"
                android:gradientRadius="50%">
            </gradient>
        </shape>
    </item>
```

It works fine with Lollipop, but it doesn't work at all on API level 19. The image simply not show there.

Is there an alternative way to do so?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Use my library. This effect u can draw only with canvas. 
https://github.com/GIGAMOLE/TintLayout